# Google Analytics and return false

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to insert Google Analytics code into a website. This chunk of code gets put on every page:

```
<!--Google Analytics account for all smithmicro sites-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-166807-32']);
                _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
                _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'smithmicro.com']);
                _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'ecommerce', 'fastspring', 3]);

                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
                ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
                ga.async = true;
                ga.src = "https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js";

                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                })();
                </script>
<!--END Google Analytics account for all smithmicro sites-->
```

Then this code is a buy button:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://sites.fastspring.com/smithmicro/checkout/23492?source=microsite " target="_top" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this]); return false;" ><input type="submit" value="Buy Physical" class="button"  /></form>
```

It works fine if I take out the "return false;" However I'm told that needs to be there for the analytics to work. I tried changing it from a form to just a link with the same parameters and got the same results."

Answer (score 0):

in this context, `return false` will result in the form submission not happening, because you are providing your own custom form processing function (in this case `_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this]); return false;`) but you aren't actually processing the form data.

I'm not sure where you heard that you needed return false, but I don't think you do. In fact, unless you're submitting the form via javascript, nothing should happen if you return false.

I believe that for LINKS the `onclick` handler should contain a `return false` because in this case the default action of navigating away isn't desired, rather the link hit should be recorded then something sent to google then the user should go to the page referenced by the link.

On this page at least they aren't using `return false` in the form's `onsubmit` event handler:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples

Also always make sure you're looking at the right documentation (there are different versions of analytics which may behave differently).

Comment: Thanks! My co-worker seems to think the return false is necessary. I did get it to work by replacing "this" with the link url. Hopefully that will satisfy them. :)

Comment: I also confuse on "true" or "false" i using GTM with datalayer push, in my case, return "false" is equal to success.